# Using Dataflow Runner I want to write data to local files

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-storage

I am have written python code to read data from GCP datastore and write to PDF. Using DirectRunner I am able to write data to PDF files but using DataflowRunner I am not able to do the same.

```
Problem statement is to read data from Datastore and convert into PDF and store it to GCS
```

Comment: Can you share a code snippet please ?

Comment: Also, the error/problem that you're getting when using Dataflow.

Answer (score 2):

Dataflow is a distributed processing system. For each step of your pipeline, it could be distributed on several node (or workers) or even multi threaded on the same node. You don't control that.

And at the end the cluster is tear down.

For those 2 main reasons (cluster deletion and distributed computing on several node), it makes no sense to store data locally. The correct pattern is to store the data out of the cluster, in Cloud Storage for example, as the error recommend it to you.

Direct runner works because it is for testing purpose and run on only 1 node (your computer).